# Python JSON Field Modification

Tags: python, json, formatting

I have a JSON query (attached at end) where I'd like to modify the field "where" with two inputs to my function

```
def jsonValue(columnName, columnValue):

    with open('payload.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
        jsonObject = json.load(jsonFile)
    
    queryTable = "{}:{\"values\":[{}]}".format(columnName, columnValue)
    jsonObject["where"] = queryTable

    with open('payload.json', 'w') as jsonFile:
        json.dump(jsonObject, jsonFile)
```

instead returns `"where": "{ \"SecurityId\":{\"values\":[1]} }"` when in the JSON file it should be `"where": {"SecurityId":{"values":[1]}}`. How can I remove the outer quotations and have nested double quotations without getting a key error. (I can't use `jsonObject["where"][columnName]` to edit the value as I that changes). Also " ' ' " doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a string when stored, but represented by Python objects when loaded. Create the new element as objects, not a string:

```py
def jsonValue(columnName, columnValue):

    with open('payload.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
        jsonObject = json.load(jsonFile)
    
    queryTable = {columnName: {"values": [columnValue]}}
    jsonObject["where"] = queryTable

    with open('payload.json', 'w') as jsonFile:
        json.dump(jsonObject, jsonFile)
```

Note that if `"where"` must be updated with possibly several `columnName`s, set its `columnName` field instead:

```py
def jsonValue(columnName, columnValue):
    with open('payload.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
        jsonObject = json.load(jsonFile)
    #             v get field or set+get field if it does not exist
    jsonObject.setdefault("where", {})[columnName] = {"values": [columnValue]}
    with open('payload.json', 'w') as jsonFile:
        json.dump(jsonObject, jsonFile)
```

Comment: Thank for the help, further down the line I will need to modify the base fields as well so this is even more helpful.